# Database design private message system (regarding delete)

Tags: mysql

I have the following database design (MySQL):

```
id|message_id|reply_id|user_id_from|user_id_to|title|message|sent_date|read_date|type

id INT(11) Auto-increment 
message_id INT(11) 
reply_id INT(11)
user_id_from INT(11)
user_id_to INT(11)
title TEXT
message  TEXT
sent_date DATETIME
read_date DATETIME
type VARCHA(255)
```

Now I have encountered the "problem" on how to best soft delete a message. If user 1 (of a conversation) delete the message his/hers inbox it should not be deleted in the user 2's inbox.

How should I best approach this? Should I have to column where I store if user 1 have deleted the message and a second column if user 2 have deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two `datetime` columns like this:

```
user_from_deleted_on DATETIME
user_to_deleted_on DATETIME
```

If the column is `NULL`, the message hasn't been deleted by that user. That way, you can record each users' deletions separately and also have an audit trail of when these events happened. You can also undelete a message by setting the column back to `NULL`.